# Second monitor resolution adjustment?

Tags: display, resolution

I have a 2018 MacBook Pro and am using an Asus VA327 monitor as a second screen.  The monitor's native resolution is 1920x1080, but for some reason, the mac won't output content at this resolution.  This results in everything being pretty big on the screen (i was hoping to use it as almost 2 screens, since there is so much real estate on it).

Does anyone know how best to do this?

[image]

Comment: What resolution *is* macOS showing on the monitor instead of its native resolution? What does System Preferences list for possible resolutions for that display (perhaps a screenshot)?

Comment: @grg it's defaulting to 1080p.  I'll add a screenshot

Comment: Try showing more resolutions by selecting the Scaled radio button while holding the alt/option key, does 1080p show up then?

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, @grg.  1080p is showing up - I am trying to get it to output at 1920x1080, which is not showing up.  And I did option-click!

Comment: 1080p is 1920x1080, they are the same thing…?

Comment: How do you have this connected?  DVI or HDMI (or something else)?  How are you making the signal conversion?  Have you tried a lower refresh rate?

Comment: What you have is a screen more than twice the size of your MacBook Pro's screen, yet has only a quarter of the resolution. 1920x1080 is, as @grg says, 1080p. That's it. That's all it can do. On a 31" screen everything's going to look huge. It will be great for watching TV on though.